# How to embed a GET[] parameter here?

Tags: php

I want that whenever I go to:

`file.php?number=999`

the value `999` will be a part of the code like this:

`$lookup->setItemId("999");`

I'm not sure how to write it correctly, this one doesn't work:

`$lookup->setItemId("($_GET["number"])");`

and not any other variation I've tried

Comment: `$lookup->setItemId($_GET["number"]);` should be fine.

Comment: Check if number parameter is set with `isset($_GET["number"])`

Comment: Thanks @TwoStraws it works now

Answer (score 0):

`$lookup->setItemId($_GET["number"]);`, Thanks @TwoStraws

Comment: It is not okay to repeat someone else's answer to claim more rep

Comment: sorry, I just didn't want to delete the question and didn't want people to keep sending in answers.